# How to detect if app has been started or brought to front?

Tags: android

I have to detect how many times the app has either been started from the icon or brought back to front from the multitasking view. How do I do that?

Comment: When app starts, `onCreate()` is called followed by `onResume()`. When brought to front from multitasking view, `onResume()` is called but not `onCreate()`.

Comment: onResume is also called if you go back from the next activity to the previous one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class can help you a lot

Following is some example code

```
RunningTaskInfo foregroundTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0); String foregroundTaskPackageName = foregroundTaskInfo .topActivity.getPackageName();
                        PackageManager pm = ForegroundAppService.this.getPackageManager();
                        PackageInfo foregroundAppPackageInfo;

                            foregroundAppPackageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(foregroundTaskPackageName, 0);
                             String foregroundTaskAppName = foregroundAppPackageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                             Drawable appicon=getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(foregroundTaskPackageName);
                             iv.setImageDrawable(appicon); //                            Log.d("Foreground task ",foregroundTaskAppName); //                             Log.d("Size ",tasklist.size()+"");
                             Log.d("App Icon ------------------------------->",appicon+"");
                             if(Globals.tasklist.size()>=1)
                             {   String value="";
                             i=0;
                                 for(HashMap<String, String> map: Globals.tasklist) {
                                     Log.d("map ",map.get("appname"));

                                     for(String str:map.keySet())
                                     {
                                         Log.d("str ",str);
                                         String key=str;
                                         value=map.get(str);
                                         Log.d("Foreground App Name ",foregroundTaskAppName);
                                         Log.d("Existing List Value   ",value);

                                        if(value.equals(foregroundTaskAppName))
                                             {

                                                flag=false;
                                                Log.d("time ",map.get("apptime"));
                                                foregroundAppTime = timeIncrement(Integer.parseInt(map.get("apptime")));
                                                map.put("apptime", Integer.toString(foregroundAppTime));
                                                Log.d("time ",map.get("apptime")); ////                                             Log.d("Previous Time ",tasklist.get(key)+"");
                                                HashMap<String,String> hs=new HashMap<String,String>();
                                                hs=Globals.tasklist.get(i);
                                                Set set=hs.entrySet();
                                                Iterator ii = set.iterator();

                                                 if(ii.hasNext()) {
                                                     Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)ii.next();
                                                     Log.d("Task -----------> ",me.getKey()+"");
                                                     Log.d("Time ----------->",me.getValue()+"");
                                                      //                                                     try //                                                  { //                                                    foregroundAppTime= timeIncrement((int)me.getValue()); //                                                    } //                                                    catch(Exception ex){Log.d("Error ",ex.getMessage());} //                                                    hs.put("apptime", Integer.toString(foregroundAppTime)); //                                                  Globals.tasklist.add(i, hs);
                                                 }
                                                 //                                             Globals.appinfo.put("appname", foregroundTaskAppName); //                                                Globals.appinfo.put("apptime", Integer.toString(foregroundAppTime)); //                                                 Globals.tasklist.add(Globals.appinfo);
                                                break;
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                 flag=true;
                                             }
                                    }
                                     if(flag==false)
                                     {
                                         break;
                                     }
                                     i++;
                                 }

                                 if(flag)
                                 {
                                     Log.d("Foreground App Name in End ",foregroundTaskAppName);
                                     HashMap<String, String> appinfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                     appinfo.put("appname", foregroundTaskAppName);
                                    appinfo.put("apptime", "0");
                                     Globals.tasklist.add(appinfo);

                                 }

                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 HashMap<String, String> appinfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                appinfo.put("appname", foregroundTaskAppName);
                                appinfo.put("apptime", "0");
                                 Globals.tasklist.add(appinfo);
                             }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            Log.d("Error ",e.getMessage());
                        }
                        Log.d("Running Task " ,"---------------Start-----------------");

                         for(HashMap<String, String> map: Globals.tasklist) {
                             for(String str:map.keySet())
                             {
                                 String key=str;
                                 String value=map.get(str);
                                 Log.d("Key ",key);
                                 Log.d("Value ",value);
                             }
                         }


                    Log.d("Running Task " ,"---------------End-----------------");
                }}, 0, 1000);   



          return START_STICKY;
       }

       int timeIncrement(int time)
       {
           time++; //          Log.d("New Time ",time+"");
           return time;
       }
```

Comment: Next time, when you copy paste, can you at least correct the indentation ? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks I will experiment with this

Comment: This is the only answer that is not extremely misleading. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In your onCreate() Method read your counter from SharedPreferences increment it and save it.

In your onResume() Method do the same with your other counter.

Comment: I have a few activities. There is no guarantee which activity has been visited last, before the user has "minimized" the app. Also when moving from one activity to another, and then back to the first one, onResume is also called, and user has never left the app.